# Java - Help solving application problem

Tags: java

I have a class that creates objects from another class, reading the necessary data from a file. Basically, it's a `thread` that loads the data and adds to a `queue`. The data it loads is a String and an Integer per time. The problem is that the app will have 2 of those classes, so 2 threads reading from one file and addin on a queue.
I'm having a lot of problems with it, so how would be the best method I could do in order to make the 2 classes add objects in the queue?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are the problems you're having?

Answer (score 1):

[BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

[ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)

Answer (score 1):

the best way will be to use semaphores......
consider using [semaphores](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)

[here is a link](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/java-semaphore) of and example on how to use it....

hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are referring to is the typical producer-consumer problem.

[Producer/Consumer threads using a Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332537/producer-consumer-threads-using-a-queue)
should help.

Answer (score 0):

You're having a synchronization issue.   Do you *truly* need two threads?   If so, put the code that adds to the queue into a  `synchronized` block.