# Android : How to wait for QR code scanner to finish and then continue for next scan in main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am new to android development

I use [this QR code scanner library](https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner)

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CodeScannerView scannerView = findViewById(R.id.scanner_view);
        mCodeScanner = new CodeScanner(this, scannerView);
        mCodeScanner.setDecodeCallback(new DecodeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDecoded(@NonNull final Result result) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        scannerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mCodeScanner.startPreview();
            }
        });       
    }
```

I am able to get the qr code result in onDecoded method for once successfully.

I need to scan QR multiple times so I tried using for loop, but my need is wait for the first QR to be scanned, and then go for next scan.

```
for(int i =0;i<10;i++) {
   mCodeScanner.startPreview();
   // wait for first QR to finish scanning and then go for next iteration
}
```

I tried using wait() and notify() but it simply crashes on wait() statement without any error throwing
[How to notify another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329654/how-to-notify-another-thread)

Comment: I was using this library . I have changed to MLKit QR - it works much better https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to scan QR multiple times...

Why not start each next scan from within the `onDecoded` callback?

> I tried using wait() and notify() but it simply crashes...

If you are asking what went wrong there, then you should show the code that crashes in your question.

Comment: I need the result back in the for loop main thread. After that lots of operation happens based on the QR output. Then it goes for next iteration.

Comment: I rewrote the logic and started the next scan from onDecoded method.