# is there a java pattern for a process to constantly run to poll or listen for messages off a queue and process them?

Tags: java, message-queue, messaging

planning on moving a lot of our single threaded synchronous processing batch jobs to a more distributed architecture with workers. the thought is having a master process read records off the database, and send them off to a queue. then have a multiple workers read off the queue to process the records in parallel.

is there any well known java pattern for a simple CLI/batch job that constantly runs to poll/listen for messages on queues? would like to use that for all the workers. or is there a better way to do this? should the listener/worker be deployed in an app container or can it be just a standalone program?

thanks

edit: also to note, im not looking to use JavaEE/JMS, but more hosted solutions like SQS, a hosted RabbitMQ, or IronMQ

Comment: What about a service bus?

Comment: It's not limited to Java, but you're describing a [producer / consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) system.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332537/producer-consumer-threads-using-a-queue

Comment: thanks - that's the type of systems i had been reading about. more specifically to the java consumer/worker though, i was wondering if it was bad practice to just do while (true) when waiting for messages or if there was a better way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a JavaEE application server (and if not, you should), you don't have to program that logic by hand since the application server does it for you.

You then implement and deploy a [message driven bean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpk.html) that listens to a queue and processes the message received. The application server will manage a connection pool to listen to queue messages and create a thread with an instance of your message driven bean which will receive the message and be able to process it.

The messages will be processed concurrently since the application server will have a connection pool and a thread pool available to listen to the queue.

All JavaEE-featured application servers like IBM Websphere or JBoss have configurations available in their admin consoles to create Message Queue listeners depending or the message queue implementation and then bind this message queue listeners to your Message Driven Bean.

Comment: Even if he's not using JavaEE, he can use only JMS with an implementation like ActiveMQ.

Comment: @F.Böller yes he could, but he also would need to implement the connection and listener pool logic, which is already done in a JavaEE application server.

Comment: No, there are client implementations for JMS available. You can use JMS without an application server. I used it in two programs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't a lot about this, and I maybe don't really answer your question, but I tried something a few month ago that might interest you to deals with message queue.

You can have a look at this: http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

I seems [Work Queue](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html) could fix your requirements.