# How to implement context-switching in java multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two methods in one class
Method 1:Write BufferedImage data to a each folder inside directory B so that in each folder there are 1 image file.

```
BufferedImage Array = ...;
for(int a = 0;a < B.listfiles().length;a++)
   write Arrray[a] to B.listfiles()[a];
```

Method 2: Write data already created from  each folder in B to each folder in directory C

```
  for(int a = 0;a < C.listfiles().length;a++)
   write B.listfiles()[a] to C.listfiles()[a]
```

How do i implement Multithreading so that an image data can be transferred to a folder in C right after an image is written to a folder in B something like this:

```
write to folder 1 in B
write to folder 1 in C using data just created from folder 1.
write to folder 2 in B
write to folder 2 in C using data just created from folder 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a queue in `C` that is accessed by `B`. So, as soon as `B` finishes with a file, it adds it to a queue for `C` to pull from and do its thing. That is the simplest answer.

```
for (int a = 0; a < B.listfiles().length; a++) {
   write Array[a] to B.listfiles()[a];
   boolean callNotify = C.queuedfiles().isEmpty();
   queue Array[a] to C.queuedfiles();
   if (callNotify) notify();
}

while(true) {
   if (C.queuedfiles().isEmpty()) wait();
   write C.queuedfiles().poll() to C.listfiles()[a];
}
```

Something like this. You then need to implement something for terminating `C` once `B` is finished

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a producer/consumer problem. Here are some examples of how you can implement that:

1. [Java BlockingQueue Example implementing Producer Consumer Problem](http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem)
2. [Producer Consumer Design Pattern with Blocking Queue Example in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/producer-consumer-design-pattern-with.html)
3. [Producer/Consumer threads using a Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332537/producer-consumer-threads-using-a-queue)