# How can a child thread send continuous messages to main thread(method) in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-threads

I have a HashMap of people who want to communicate with each other as follows:

```
{zidane=[rooney, rooney, rooney, scholes, rooney], rooney=[scholes, messi, scholes], scholes=[ronaldo], ronaldo=[rooney, messi, scholes], messi=[zidane]}
```

Here, each person in the key will have their own threads in which they will send a message to each person in their list and receive a response.

```
public class Master {
    public Map callsMap = new HashMap<String, List>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Master m = new Master();
        m.readFile();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
        List<Future<String>> returnFutures = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, List>> it = m.callsMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, List> pair = it.next();
            String caller = pair.getKey();
            List receiverList = pair.getValue();
            returnFutures.add(executorService.submit(new SubTasks(caller, receiverList) ));
        }

        while(executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        for(Future<String> returnFuture: returnFutures){
            System.out.println(returnFuture.get());
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The `Master` class will iteratively create a thread for every key in the HashMap. Please note that the `readFile` method will just read from a text file and produce the input (into `callsMap` variable) I have mentioned above. It is not particularly important for this context so I have omitted it here.

I have the `SubTasks` class which implements the `Callable` interface and creates messages for each interaction. This class will not create any additional threads but just operate on the caller and receiver list it received as follows:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public  class SubTasks implements Callable<String> {
    private String caller;
    private List receiverList;
    private volatile String returnMessage;
    private volatile String callerMessage;
    private volatile String str = "";

    SubTasks(String s, List l){
        caller = s;
        receiverList = l;
    }

    @Override
    public String call (){
        for (int i = 0; i < receiverList.size(); i++) {
            callerMessage = receiverList.get(i)+" received intro message from "+caller +" ["+System.currentTimeMillis()+"]";
            //System.out.println(callerMessage);
            returnMessage = caller+" received reply message from "+receiverList.get(i) +" ["+System.currentTimeMillis()+"]";
            //System.out.println(returnMessage);
            str = str + callerMessage +"\n"+ returnMessage +"\n";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

If I directly print in the child threads, I get the desired result as the messages are being printed in random order:

```
rooney received intro message from zidane [1592165414388]
ronaldo received intro message from scholes [1592165414388]
scholes received intro message from rooney [1592165414388]
rooney received intro message from ronaldo [1592165414389]
zidane received intro message from messi [1592165414389]
scholes received reply message from ronaldo [1592165414434]
zidane received reply message from rooney [1592165414434]
...
...
```

But I want these messages to be printed in the main method instead of the child threads. I tried to return the messages by concatenating the `returnMessage` and `callerMessage` but since I return at the end of each thread, they appear to be printed sequentially (call-reply for each pair) as follows:

```
rooney received intro message from zidane [1592165584566]
zidane received reply message from rooney [1592165584614]
rooney received intro message from zidane [1592165584632]
zidane received reply message from rooney [1592165584632]
rooney received intro message from zidane [1592165584632]
zidane received reply message from rooney [1592165584632]
...
...
```

So, my question is how do I print each `callerMessage` and `returnMessage` in the main method instead of the child threads as soon as they are created?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a classic example of producer-consumer problem, where your `SubTasks` are producers, and `Master` is a single consumer. It can be solved in multiple different ways using low-level java concurrency constructs, but the simplest one would probably be by using some kind of thread safe intermediary Queue. You can start by taking a look at [Producer/Consumer threads using a Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332537/producer-consumer-threads-using-a-queue).